# how to fix sql query error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this request

```
 DELETE FROM T1 WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x' AND 
 0<(SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE "SUBSTR"(PID,1,1)=1)  OR '1'='1'
```

but got

```
The SQL statement " DELETE FROM T1 WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x' 
AND 0<(SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE SUBSTR(PID,1,1)=1)  OR '1'='1'" 
contains the syntax error[s]: - 1:101 - SQL syntax error: the token 
"(" was not expected here
```

Please help, how I can fix it?

---

UPDATE
remove "SUBSTR" to SUBSTR, but get The SQL statement

```
DELETE FROM T1 
WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x' 
AND 0= (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE SUBSTR(PID,1,1)=1)  OR '1'='1'
```

contains the syntax error[s]: - 1:99 - SQL syntax error: the token "(" was not expected here

---

UPDATE 2

I change to

```
SELECT count(*) FROM T2 WHERE SUBSTRING("asdqweasd",1,1))
```

and get 
 - SQL syntax error: the token "," was not expected here
 - expecting "from", found ','

Comment: Why is SUBSTR quoted? - remove them

Comment: does T2 only contain one column of a numeric data type?  I'm baffled how a `select *` can be > or =... perhaps change * to the specific column of numeric data type.   I strongly suspect t2 has more than one column though... However, if it is only one column, the data type doesn't appear to be numeric based on the fact your substringing PID...  and just curious since or '1'='1' will always be true, aren't you infact deleting everything from t1 where permission_ID = 'x' so everything after that is moot anyway?

Comment: What do you expect when compare `0` (inteeger value) with `(SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE SUBSTR(PID,1,1)=1)` recordset? it has no sense to me

Comment: The question is about a *syntax* error; specifically, about the unexpected presence of `(`.  Note that sqlite doesn't complain about this (*syntactically*, anyway).

Comment: Update 2 has two errors that I see.  1st you have an extra `)` at the end second where substring... will return `a`  2nd ... but no equality is defined  so `where a` is invalid SQL syntax... if you had `WHERE SUBSTRING("asdqweasd",1,1)='a'` it may work.  You appear to be struggling with basic SQL constructs, you may want to spend some time on SQLzoo.net or similar to better get a handle on basics.

Comment: `SUBSTRING("asdqweasd",1,1)='a'` don't help ((

Comment: You are doing something different than you tell us. check my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/102d8/1  your query is good.  My guess, you are not using MYSQL? maybe you have MSSQL?

Comment: I use  opensql syntax

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Double quotes around SUBSTR. Also you can not use SELECT * . Use count(*)

```
DELETE FROM T1 WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x' AND 
 0<(SELECT count(*) FROM T2 WHERE SUBSTR(PID,1,1)=1)  OR '1'='1'
```

Comment: DELETE FROM T1 WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x' AND 0=(SELECT count(*) FROM T2 WHERE SUBSTR(PID,1,1)=1)  OR '1'='1'" contains the syntax error[s]: - 1:106 - SQL syntax error: the token "(" was not expected here